# Как составить из 2 запросов один, который будет выводить больше столбцов из одной таблицы?

Tags: sql

Вопрос состоит в том чтобы составить из 2 запросов один, который будет выводить больше столбцов из одной таблицы
пример первого запроса:

```
SELECT [HospitalID_Ref],
       count(*) as 'Зарегистрированно '
FROM [REMD].[dbo].[MedicalDocument]
where MedicalDocumentDate between '20230101' and '20230118 23:59:59' and MedicalDocumentTypeID_Ref=141 and sent = 1 
group by HospitalID_Ref
```

он выводит таблицу из двух столбцов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример второго запроса

```
SELECT [HospitalID_Ref],
       count(*) as 'успешно'
FROM [REMD].[dbo].[MedicalDocument]
where MedicalDocumentDate between '20230101' and '20230118 23:59:59' and MedicalDocumentTypeID_Ref=141 and REMDID is not null
group by HospitalID_Ref
```

он выводит другую информацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне из этих двух запросов сделать один который будет выводить инфу так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Обрати особое внимание на раздел "Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке"

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT HospitalID_Ref,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sent = 1           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Зарегистрировано',
       SUM(CASE WHEN remdid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Успешно'
FROM [REMD].[dbo].[MedicalDocument]
WHERE MedicalDocumentDate BETWEEN '20230101' AND '20230118 23:59:59' 
  AND MedicalDocumentTypeID_Ref = 141 
-- AND (sent = 1 OR remdid IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY HospitalID_Ref
```

Comment: Очень благодарен за ответ
Можно мне пожалуйста объяснить 2 и 3-ю строчку, что они делают 
если я захочу самостоятельно добавить столбцы новые в данный запрос

Comment: @Вадим А что собственно в этих выражениях непонятно-то? По-моему, всё настолько прозрачно... я даже представить не могу, что тут требует объяснения.

Comment: @Вадим Просто считается количество строк в выборке, удовлетворяющих условию. И правда непонятно, что там объяснять. Почитайте документацию про `SUM`, про `CASE`, это довольно типовое применение `CASE` собственно.